# Make this for-loop more efficient?

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, optimization

- - edit - -
    This code will be run with optimizations off

    ---

full transparency this is a homework assignment.

I’m having some trouble figuring out how to optimize this code...

My instructor went over unrolling and splitting but neither seems to greatly reduce the time needed to execute the code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

    // You can change anything between this comment ...

    int     j;

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }

    // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the *same
    // number of additions as this one does.

}
```

Comment: *"but neither seems to greatly reduce the time needed to execute the code"* - Why? Did you measure it as no better?

Comment: Are we missing something about the type of stuff that is in the array? eg. is it an ordered list of numbers between `n` and `n+ARRAY_SIZE*x`?

Comment: @StoryTeller the goal of the assignment is to have to code run in under 7 seconds. I was able to shave off about 2 seconds using unrolling but it was still taking about 14 seconds to execute the code.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox the array is just an integer array all initialized to 0

Comment: Run it on a better computer. Seriously, "it has to run in seven seconds" is a ridiculous requirement.

Comment: @IngoBürk unfortunately it has to be run on our schools Linux server

Comment: Change it to only add 0s. I don't see the question saying you need to add the same numbers — you just need to do the same number of additions. Chances are the compiler will optimize it away then.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean same number of additions to `sum` at runtime (rather than same number of additions in the *source code*), unrolling could give you something like:

```
for (j = 0; j + 5 < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 5) {
    sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4];
}
for (; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
    sum += array[j];
}
```

Alternatively, since you're adding the *same* values each time through the outer loop, you don't need to process it `N_TIMES` times, just do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
    // You can change anything between this comment ...
    int     j;
    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }
    sum *= N_TIMES;
    break;
    // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the *same
    // number of additions as this one does.
}
```

This requires that the initial value of `sum` is zero, which is likely but there's actually nothing in your question that mandates this, so I include it as a pre-condition for this method.

Comment: For your second idea, you can create a separate `tmpsum`, multiply that by `N_TIMES` then add the result to `sum`

Comment: If `ARRAY_SIZE % 5 != 0` you are skipping the last `ARRAY_SIZE % 5` elements, as `j >= ARRAY_SIZE` after the first loop has terminated. The second part violates the constraints, same number of additions must be performed.

Comment: @ext3h Question is ambigious, but it mentions constraint only for additions in *inner loop*. There seems to be no requirement that loop itself should be repeated.

Comment: @Ext3h -- you are wrong on both counts. The first solution incorporates a second loop to sum the remaining `ARRAY_SIZE % 5` elements. And there is no constraint violation or ambiguity for the second solution: the problem clearly states that "inner loop must do the same number of additions", which this solution does.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, unless you are explicitly compiling with `-O0`, your compiler has already likely optimized this loop much further than you could possibly expect.

Including unrolling, and on top of unrolling also vectorization and more. Trying to optimize this by hand is something you should never, absolutely never do. At most you will successfully make the code harder to read and understand, while most likely not even being able to match the compiler in terms of performance.

As to why there is no measurable gain? Possibly because you already hit a bottleneck, even with the "non optimized" version. For `ARRAY_SIZE` greater than your processors cache even the compiler optimized version is already limited by memory bandwidth.

But for completeness, let's just assume you have not hit that bottleneck, and that you actually had turned optimizations almost off (so no more than `-O1`), and optimize for that.

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

    // You can change anything between this comment ...

    int j;
    int tmpSum[4] = {0,0,0,0};

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j+=4) {
        tmpSum[0] += array[j+0];
        tmpSum[1] += array[j+1];
        tmpSum[2] += array[j+2];
        tmpSum[3] += array[j+3];
    }

    sum += tmpSum[0] + tmpSum[1] + tmpSum[2] + tmpSum[3];

    if(ARRAY_SIZE % 4 != 0) {
        j -= 4;
        for (; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
            sum += array[j];
        }
    }

    // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the *same
    // number of additions as this one does.

}
```

There is pretty much only one factor left which still could have reduced the performance, for a smaller `array`.

Not the overhead for the loop, so plain unrolling would had been pointless with a modern processor. Don't even bother, you won't beat the branch prediction.

But the latency between two instructions, until a value written by one instruction may be read again by the next instruction still applies. In this case, `sum` is constantly written and read all over again, and even if `sum` is cached in a register, this delay still applies and the processors pipeline had to wait.

The way around that, is to have multiple independent additions going on simultaneously, and finally just combine the results. This is by the way also an optimization which most modern compilers do know how to perform.

On top of that, you could now also express the first loop with vector instructions - once again also something the compiler would have done. At this point you are running into instruction latency again, so you will likely have to introduce one more set of temporaries, so that you now have two independent addition streams each using vector instructions.

Why the requirement of at least `-O1`? Because otherwise the compiler won't even place `tmpSum` in a register, or will try to express e.g. `array[j+0]` as a sequence of instructions for performing the addition first, rather than just using a single instruction for that. Hardly possible to optimize in that case, without using inline assembly directly.

---

Or if you just feel like (legit) cheating:

```
const int N_TIMES = 1000;
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1024;
const int array[1024] = {1};
int sum = 0;

__attribute__((optimize("O3")))
__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))
int fastSum(const int array[]) {
      int j;
      int tmpSum;

      for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
          tmpSum += array[j];
      }
      return tmpSum;
}
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
        // You can change anything between this comment ...


        sum += fastSum(array);

        // ... and this one. But your inner loop must do the *same
        // number of additions as this one does.

    }
    return sum;
}
```

The compiler will then apply pretty much all the optimizations described above.

Comment: Thanks for all of that!

Comment: What sense does it make to use four accumulators instead of one ? You are just risking to add overhead. And your adjustment of `j` for the last chunk is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Masking the write to read latency on each of the accumulators, and allowing the parallel dispatch of the accumulations. E.g. Intels Core architecture dispatches up to 4 independent integer operations per clock cycle, but only if that many independent instructions can be found. The adjustment for the lust chunk should be correct, but I reformatted it regardless.

Comment: @Ext3h: I understand "optimizations off" as getting close to a RAM model (the optimizations you mention will not exist, the generated code will read/write the accumulator(s) every time rather then keep them in registers). In this model is makes no difference to use one or several accumulators (disregarding the consolidation). Except useless program complication.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right, `-O0` has that side effect, but it would be possible to bypass the RAM model with the `register` keyword. The bigger problem is however that it - at least in GCC - also prevents memory access with static offset to be emitted as a single instruction.

Comment: @Ext3h: in modern CPU/compilers, the `register` keyword is essentially deprecated and not influencing the generated code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Except it does at least in GCC for `-O0`.

Comment: @Ext3h: any compiler specifics are irrelevant to the question. The question is for the abstract C engine.